# Como mostra um array que vem do banco de dados em um input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lanches" id="lanches" value="<?php echo $resultado['lanches']; ?>" >
```

Tenho esse input acima aonde que o mesmo receba esse array que esta dentro do banco de dados
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php), no seu caso entendi que estaria mostrando o valor em seu input correto?

A estrutura do foreach é

```
foreach($array as $linha){

}
```

Ele vai executar uma iteração (assim como a estrutura [for](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php)), para cada linha do seu Array, e em cada iteração você irá realizar a manipulação com a variável $linha.

Por exemplo, se você tivesse esse array: $array = ["pos1", "pos2", "pos3"], o foreach iria rodar 3 vezes, e em cada iteração o valor que está sendo acessado no momento seria utilizado pela variável apos o "as" no caso do exemplo a cima a variável $linha.

No caso do seu código ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach($array as $valor){
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lanches" id="lanches" value=" <?php echo $valor; ?>" >
}
```

Comment: O código não irá funcionar. O html está solto no meio do php. Uma opção é colocar em um `echo` ou fechar o php (`?>`) antes do html e reabrir após

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um foreach. Seria mais ou menos assim:

```
    foreach($resultado['lanche'] as $id){ 
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='lanches[$id]' id='lanches_$id' value='$id'>";
}
```

Comment: flw man, brigadao...

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, use o foreach. 
documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Como faria com foreach, tenho algum exemplo de como ...